# CloudKit share participant no longer returns name

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I'm working on an app that uses CloudKit sharing functionality. The sharing features have been working great, but recently I no longer get the user names back from the `CKShare.Participant` when a user accepts the sharing request.

Details

I'm using the built-in `UICloudSharingController` to set up the share, which works and sets up the share properly.

When the invited user accepts the share, the owner gets a notification of the change in the zone and then fetches the `CKShare`.

The fetched `CKShare` object has an array of share participants (`CKShare.Participant`), which has a `nameComponents` property. I've used this in order to get the first and last name of the participants to display in the UI. This was all working fine until recently.

Now, however, I'm only getting values in `nameComponents` for the owner of the share. The accepted participants have `nil` values for the `nameComponents.givenName` and `nameComponents.familyName`.

I have not changed anything in this part of my code in some time, so don't think I've caused this. I've tried this on iOS 11, 11.4, 12, 12.1 and all have the issue. This leads me to believe there might have been a change on the server side from Apple.

**Note**
I am not requesting `.userDiscoverability` permissions. I have not had to do that in order to get the names once a user accepts. I realize that I *can* request that and then use `CKDiscoverUserIdentitiesOperation` to get the names. But I'd rather not as I don't want the dialog, which is confusing for users.

Has anyone seen this change? Or better, yet, does anyone have any suggestions for tracking down the cause or fixing it?

Thanks.

Comment: I've run into the same issue. Feels like Apple has changed this because of privacy concerns.

Comment: Thanks, @zoef. I’ve submitted a bug to Apple and will post any information I receive.

Comment: I, too, have been exploring an implementation of sharing that uses custom UI.  if I use the built-in UI to add a person to a share, the name does appear, but its probably because the UI is sniffing the address info entered by the user.  If I use my own UI and add participants via code, if I identify them with a record ID, no name appears, whereas if I identify them with an email or phone number, a name appears. very frustrating. fwiw.